# how redirect output of a *.cmd file that contains start command to a file?

Tags: command-line, batch-file, windows-xp

If I put on a console this command:

```
start /b /belownormal /wait php.exe script.php > output.txt
```

All goes well, but if I put the same command but without redirection to a *.cmd file and then do redirection on that file:

So the file myscript.cmd is as follows:

```
start /b /belownormal /wait php.exe script.php
```

And command I have problem with is:

```
myscript.cmd > output.txt
```

The output.txt is being created but is empty.
Is there any other way to run any command line application with 'below normal' priority and be able to redirect output to a file ?

(Of course this has nothing to do particularly with php. Any command has this effect even simple echo.)

Comment: maybe you can do this trick: (in 1.bat) start /b /belownormal /wait 2.bat (in 2.bat) php.exe script.php > output.txt

Comment: On Win7 64bit I'm unable to reproduce the above behavior

Comment: Seconding that (Win7 SP1 64-bit). These were the steps I took to try and reproduce the issue: 1) `echo @start /b /belownormal /wait cmd /c echo NOT every command has this effect> test.bat`; 2) `test.bat > testdir`; 3) `type testdir`. And guess what was the output of the last command?

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this trick may solve your problem. myscript.cmd:

```
start /b /belownormal /wait php.exe script.php %~1
```

and call it this way:

```
myscript.cmd "> output.txt"
```

Comment: But wouldn't the redirection apply to the `start` command in this case?

Comment: Yes, exactly as the OP wants! :)

Comment: Indeed. At first I thought they wanted the output to be applied to `php.exe` (and the PHP script), but I can see now that nothing in their example suggests that.

Comment: But... If they want the output of `start` to be redirected, then *normal* redirection applied to the cmd script should do the same, shouldn't it? I mean, if you redirect the output of a batch script, the redirection is applied to the output of every command in the script, so `myscript.cmd > output.txt` should work for `start` as well (without any tricks).

Comment: Yes, I thought the same at first, but it seems that processes STARTed via a Batch file does not inherit the standard handles, but _recreate_ they instead. Else, you may start an automatic edition of a file in Notepad, for example, by redirecting the keyboard input commands for such edition this way: `start /b anyfile.txt < editCommands.txt`

Comment: I finally managed to try to reproduce the issue, and... there was no issue. Please see my comment to the original post.

Answer (score 1):

Try escaping the redirection with a caret, `^`, i.e.

`myscript.cmd ^> output.txt`